# Why doesn't my capitalization function run as expected?

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure what is wrong with my code. I want to capitalize each word from input field and display it in "showcase".

Below is my code:

Convert

```
<script>
function convert(sst) {
    return sst.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sst.slice(1);
    document.getElementById("showcase").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is `n`? It's only mentioned once.

Comment: HINT: Why do you return from the store before buying groceries?

Comment: Almost anything after return statement is unreachable.

Comment: Depending on your application, you mind find the CSS `text-transform:capitalize` helpful; "...forcing the first letter of each word to be converted to uppercase." See [text-transform @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform).

Answer (score 2):

- You have a return before `document.getElementById("showcase").innerHTML = n;`
- You didn't declare the variable `n`.

**Look at this code snippet with those fixes:**

```js
function convert(sst) {
    return sst.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sst.slice(1);        
}

// To reuse your function 'convert', just return the converted value.
document.getElementById("showcase").innerHTML = convert("ele");
```

```html
<p id="showcase">
</p>
```

See? now it's working your logic.

**Important:**  Your approach works for one word only :-)

## UPDATE

**This is your approach to capitalized all words**

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("showcase").innerHTML = convert(document.getElementById('inputfield').value);
});

function convert(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase()
  });
}
```

```html
<body> <input type="text" id="inputfield" /> <button id='myButton'>Convert</button>
  <div id="showcase"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: set a `return n` at the end of the function for good measure...?

Comment: @Endless do you think that's important according to what the OP wants to do?

Comment: Maybe not, but it's better to return something than undefined. I would have made it a pure function so it dose one thing anyway... `innerHTML = convert()`

Comment: seeing that he had a return statement means he could want to display in the view while also getting back the value

Comment: <body>
    <input type="text" id="inputfield"/>
    <button onclick="convert(document.getElementById('inputfield'))">Convert</button>
   <div id="showcase"></div>

    <script>
    function convert(str) {
        return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt){
          return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        });
        document.getElementById("showcase").innerText = str;
      }
      
      
    </script>
</body>

Comment: I could not copy all my code. I need to convert a input string from user, not a string defined by developer, here is my full code, not sure how to do it ?<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputfield"/>
    <button onclick="convert(document.getElementById('inputfield'))">Convert</button>
   <div id="showcase"></div>
    <script>
    function convert(str) {
        return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt){
          return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase() });
        document.getElementById("showcase").innerText = str; }    
    </script>
</body>

Answer (score 1):

It is better to return a value from the convert function so you can re-use the function:

```
<script>
    function convert(sst) {
        return sst.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sst.slice(1);
    }
    var n = convert('hello');
    document.getElementById("showcase").innerHTML = n;
    var m = convert('world');
    document.getElementById("otherElement").innerHTML = m;
</script>
```

Comment: I could not copy all my code. I need to convert a input string from user, not a string defined by developer, here is my full code, not sure how to do it ?<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputfield"/>
    <button onclick="convert(document.getElementById('inputfield'))">Convert</button>
   <div id="showcase"></div>
    <script>
    function convert(str) {
        return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt){
          return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase() });
        document.getElementById("showcase").innerText = str; }    
    </script>
</body>

Answer (score 1):

This will **capitalize each word** unlike the other answers
One other different is that it will lowercase the other letters that follows (like sTRING in this example)
similar to the others this also return a value from the function so you can re-use the function, this is also called a pure function doing just one thing.

```js
function capitalizeWords(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt){
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}

var str = capitalizeWords('js sTRING exercises');
document.getElementById("showcase").innerText = str;
```

```html
<p id="showcase"></p>
```

Also notice that i switched from `innerHTML` to `innerText` for better safety. Any dangerous html code could sneak in if using innerHTML

Comment: I could not copy all my code. I need to convert a input string from user, not a string defined by developer, here is my full code, not sure how to do it ?<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputfield"/>
    <button onclick="convert(document.getElementById('inputfield'))">Convert</button>
   <div id="showcase"></div>
    <script>
    function convert(str) {
        return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt){
          return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase() });
        document.getElementById("showcase").innerText = str; }    
    </script>
</body>